# How do I add charset to Knex.js connection string?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, utf-8, knex.js

I am using Knex.js for database connections. I would like to use a connection string instead of the connection object for connecting to a database and be able to specify the `charset`.

Example:

`connection: 'mysql://root:secret@127.0.0.1:3306/test-db'`

NOT

```
connection: {
    host     : '127.0.0.1',
    user     : 'root',
    password : 'secret',
    database : 'test-db',
    charset  : 'utf8'
}
```

I have the connection string working.

Could someone explain how I would specify the `charset` in the Knex.js connection string?

Comment: Gadzooks!, yet another 3rd party package!  If you can't figure it out, execute `SET NAMES utf8` right after connecting; that's usually a valid fallback.

Comment: The knex docs says that it passes the connection string directly to the underlying driver: http://knexjs.org/#Installation-client . If so, the underlying driver might not be showing the expected behavior: https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#establishing-connections . I'm just guessing, but it may worth the try.

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful. The docs show the below connection string which looks promising:   connection = mysql.createConnection('mysql://user:pass@host/db?debug=true&charset=BIG5_CHINESE_CI&timezone=-0700');

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
connection: 'mysql://root:secret@127.0.0.1:3306/test-db?charset=utf8mb4'
```

See connection string options as described here: https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#connection-options